# Result from xml2js

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js

I'm trying to parse xml after a request.

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    parseString = require('xml2js').parseString,
    request = require('request');


    request('http://www.stands4.com/services/v2/quotes.php?uid=123&tokenid=123&searchtype=RANDOM', function (error, response, body) {
       if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
           parseString(body, function (err, result) {
               console.dir(result);
        });

     }
})
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results><result><quote>Some Text</quote><author>Name</author></result></results>
```

**Returns**

```
{ results: { result: [ [Object] ] } }
```

Why it isn't returning the correct format?

Comment: How is it not returning the correct format, what is the XML that the url returned? What output did you expect?

Comment: @weeknie The XML returned is "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results><result><quote>Some Text</quote><author>Name</author></result></results>"

Comment: what is "the correct format"?

Comment: @mpm Something I can use. Because "{ results: { result: [ [Object] ] } }" is not usable.

Comment: "{ results: { result: [ [Object] ] } }" seems to be what console.dir displays, what is the actual result? it's not "{ results: { result: [ [Object] ] } }" , it's something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{ results: { result: [ [Object] ] } }
```

is the result of console.dir , not the actual value of result.

if you want to know what is the result,try

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```